# How to Test/Verify a Multiple Linear Regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model

I have a hard time figuring out the best way to test/verify a multiple regression. Basically, last semester I had a machine learning class where I was taught to always test models with unseen data. On the other hand, in my stats class, I learned to basically just verify the parameters(p-values, f-test, R, R^2, adjusted R^2, vif, bic, cp, etc.) to identify the best regression.

I am currently doing a small challenge to predict the chance of students being accepted at their top universities. I have a data set of past students (train set) and data of students that will graduate (the one I'm trying to predict the value of). I am evaluated on " You will be evaluated solely on your prediction accuracy using Mean Square Error (MSE)".

I want to know whether I should split the train set so I have a test set? I currently did the best subsets regression with the entire train set and chose the best model by analyzing at adjusted R^2, bic, Cp, p-value, vif and Breusch-Pagan test. Basically, how I learned in stats class, but should I do the same thing but split the train set so that I have a test set to actually verify the linear regression for overfitting?

Sorry for the question, it's the first time I'm trying to put into application what I learned in class.

Also, would other models be better for this challenge (decision trees, random forest or other ML models)?

Comment: The challenge you are participating in sets the goal: minimize MSE. It is a fairly safe assumption that this is meant to be MSE on test data rather than training data.